# Selecting the "right" child

Tags: c++, qt

on a dialog form a have a few items, amongs them I have a QListView and QTreeView.
I'd like to load them to a QSet during initialization of this dialog.  What's the best way to do it?

Comment: They are two different types, so you'll always suffer from some form of type erasure.  Why do you want to do this?

Comment: @cbamber85 I'd like to make this dialog generic in a sense that if I in the future will add some other view it will be automatically detected and connected to a model without me doing anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could loop through the children of the dialog, try to cast them to `QAbstractItemView*` and add those that pass:

```
#include <QtGui>

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  QApplication app(argc, argv);

  QVBoxLayout *layout = new QVBoxLayout;
  layout->addWidget(new QLabel("Hello!"));
  layout->addWidget(new QListView);
  layout->addWidget(new QTreeView);
  layout->addWidget(new QPushButton("Click me!"));

  QDialog d;
  d.setLayout(layout);
  d.show();

  QSet<QAbstractItemView*> set;
  for (int i = 0; i < d.children().size(); ++i) {
    QAbstractItemView *view = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(d.children().at(i));
    if (view) {
      set << view;
    }
  }

  qDebug() << set.size();

  return app.exec();
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. I don't think I expressed clearly what I want. Ok, I have a dialog. On this dialog I have many widgets some of them **maybe** view types (objects derived from QAbstractItemView). I want during the initialization of this dialog to detect how many of them do I have and put pointers to them into QSet<QAbstractItemView*>;

Answer (score 0):

The following may work for you (code not checked):

```
QSet<QAbstractItemView*> childViews;
for (QObjectList::iterator it = children().begin(); it != children().end(); ++it)
{
    QAbstractItemView* view = qobject_cast<QAbstractItemView*>(*it);
    if (view != 0)
    {
        childViews.insert(view);
    }
}
```